# discord.py | How do I check if the message being sent is being sent directly to the bot (DM) or in a chat?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to check to see if the message being sent (on_message()) is in a DM sent to the bot or just sent in any other place like a chat in a guild. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message type is dm:
        #do stuff
    elif message type is not dm:
        #do something else```
````

Comment: Have you looked at the discord.py documentation? It should describe exactly what properties and methods are available on the `message` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [`message.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.guild).

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild: # message is not DM
        # do stuff
    else: # message is DM
        # do something else```
````